# Magento 2.2.1 - Possible upgrade issues

Tags: magento-2.2.1

Magento 2.2.1 released today which fixes some critical vulnerabilities. https://magento.com/security/patches/magento-221-2110-and-2017-security-update

While upgrading the store from 2.2.0 to 2.2.1, I am facing below issue which I am sure many others are facing.

**Signifyd**

```
Command "update" failed: Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/module-signifyd 100.2.1 -> no matching package found.
- magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 requires magento/module-signifyd 100.2.1 -> no matching package found.
- Installation request for magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.2.1].

Potential causes:
- A typo in the package name
- The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.

For additional assistance, see component dependency help .
```

Did anyone managed to get a workaround for this?

What other issues are you facing during this upgrade?

Comment: see also https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089

Comment: thanks. yeah seeing that as well, no solution yet :(

Comment: well, give them some time to fix it ;)

Comment: I had the same issue and saw it on the official github repository and [this workaround](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089#issuecomment-342621233) worked for me. Hope it helps.

Comment: Try running it again this morning it should work. We had about 50% of our clients encountering the issue as you did. It appears that Magento's repo didn't have all the packages dispersed to all accounts, strange but like I said should work now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Workaround if you don't need the `signifyd` module: Add it to your "replace" section in the composer json as follows:

```
"replace": {
        "magento/module-signifyd": "*"
    },
```

This is the best way to remove unneeded modules. If you don't need that module as well, I'd leave that change in your composer.json. The composer.json is made for modification, your changes can stay. If you need the signifyd module, you should revert the change later of course.

Source: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089#issuecomment-342733758

Comment: It is better practice to mention source which you are using for an answer 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089#issuecomment-342621233

Comment: Upgrade works after adding this in `composer.json`

Comment: make sure you dont put that code on the bottom. thats what i did and it didnt work, needs to be in the middle

Answer (score 5):

The issue of availability of the module has been resolved by Magento. Please check upgrade Magento to version 2.2.1 now.

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition 2.2.1 --no-update
composer update
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Answer (score 4):

As Piotr commented to the Github issue linked in the comments above, the problem is a caching/permission issue.

See [here](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089#issuecomment-342706806):

> We have some caching issue on our side and not all accounts were
>   updated with permissions for the new release or signifyd module. We
>   are working to find and eliminate the root cause but in the meantime:
>
> - you can try to generate a new set of keys on Magento.com ->My Account
>     -> Marketplace. Did not test it but it might work. And use those keys in auth.json
> - you can DM me (eg on Twitter) or email
>     (peter(at)magento.com) with your pubkey or MAGEID and someone will
>     help clear the cache (it is per account, not global)

Answer (score 0):

But in case If you want to use signifyd module then you just need to follow simple step.

- Go to vendor/composer/ folder.
- Open installed.json
- Find "name": "magento/module-shipping",
- And past Below code after module-shipping

  ```
      { "name": "magento/module-signifyd",
      "version": "100.2.1",
      "dist": {
          "type": "zip",
          "url": "https://repo.magento.com/archives/magento/module-signifyd/magento-module-signifyd-100.2.1.0.zip",
          "reference": null,
          "shasum": "370e54c1f1cc00ea441f3ac99e3a6932ce9866ea"
      },
      "require": {
          "magento/framework": "101.0.*",
          "magento/module-backend": "100.2.*",
          "magento/module-checkout": "100.2.*",
          "magento/module-config": "101.0.*",
          "magento/module-customer": "101.0.*",
          "magento/module-directory": "100.2.*",
          "magento/module-payment": "100.2.*",
          "magento/module-sales": "101.0.*",
          "magento/module-store": "100.2.*",
          "php": "7.0.2|7.0.4|~7.0.6|~7.1.0"
      },
      "suggest": {
          "magento/module-config": "101.0.*"
      },
      "type": "magento2-module",
      "autoload": {
          "files": [
              "registration.php"
          ],
          "psr-4": {
              "Magento\\Signifyd\\": ""
          }
      },
      "license": [
          "proprietary"
      ],
      "description": "Submitting Case Entry to Signifyd on Order Creation"
  },
  ```
- Save this file and run composer update command

We have tried this and it's working for me.

We Hope It'll help you to solve this issues. Please let me know is it working for you or not. Also Please let Us know if you have any other better solution for that.

Thank you All,

Comment: It is better practice to mention source which you are using for an answer 
https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12089#issuecomment-342621233