# Magento 2 upgrade

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

Current Magento version is 2.1.7, So Is it safe to upgrade it to 2.2.3?

Or Should upgrade it to 2.1.12(latest in 2.1.x series)?

Answer (score 1):

You should go with Magento 2.2.3 Its more **Stable** compare to 2.1.x.

Also there's new add-Ons like **Advacned reports**, **Dotmailer**, **elastic search** etc.

For more updates regarding this check below references.
[Dev Docs](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.3CE.html)

Hope it will help you !!

Answer (score 1):

You should upgrade to **lastest 2.2.3 version**.

Yes,should be some issue when you will upgrade to latest one.

- PHP version, magento 2.2.3  only support php 7.decrypted  php 5
  version. http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.2.0EE.html
- Transfer all  serialize to fields to json fields at database. See magento doc http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/release-notes/backward-incompatible-changes.html

Also  check [Magento 2.2.1 - Possible upgrade issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/200449/magento-2-2-1-possible-upgrade-issues)

***But most  advance to upgrade to  2.2.3  that is magento bag ,Lot of magento bugs resolved at 2.2.0 version and also site speed improved.***

My suggest to upgrade at 2.2.3.